# returning Array Observable from watchQuery function GraphQL, but giving *ngFor error

Tags: angular, rxjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm getting an [ Error: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. ]

What am I doing wrong?

```
View Code : 
<div *ngFor="let item of data| async" class="wide-box">
```

Component Code :

```
public data : ApolloQueryObservable
```

Calls watchQuery function and performs some post processing in map function, and return Observable of Array,

```
public feed(){
    var a = gpl`
    query user($user: UserInput){
    user(user:$user){
        first_name
        lync{
            artist
            title
            albumArtUrl
            listenon
            date
            author{
                username
                email
            }
        }
        following{
            lync {
                artist
                title
                albumArtUrl
                listenon
                date
                author{
                  username
                  email
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
`;
this.data = this.apollo.watchQuery({
    query: a,
    variables: {
            user: {
                email: window.localStorage.getItem('email')
            }
        }
    }).map((x:any)=>x.data.user[0]).map(x=>{
        this.feedItem = []  
        if(x.lync.length){
            x.lync.map(l=>{
                if(l!=undefined){
                    this.feedItem.push(l)
                }
            })
        }
        if(x.following){
            x.following.map(y=>{
                if(y.lync.length != 0){
                    y.lync.map(l=>{
                        if(l!=undefined){
                            this.feedItem.push(l)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }

        console.log(this.feedItem, "feedItem")
        return ApolloQueryObservable.of(this.feedItem)
    })
```

To refetch data from server

```
public refresh(){
   this.data.refetch()
  }
```

Comment: I've only just spent a few minutes on the [documentation](http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/queries.html#select-pipe) but your whole approach seems completely at odds with it. For example I just linked directly to the section on working with async pipes. As I would expect, the documentation: 1. clearly advises setting up the watchQuery in the `ngOnInit()` hook, 2. Cleanly returns the observable directly from the function. It looks like you `.map()` processing is really messing with the structure. Notably `x.data.user[0]` seems really wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not uderstand what is happening, but I see that the last map operator in the watchQuery does not return any object.

Therefore it is likely that this.data gets filled with null

Comment: Note that there are `.push()` operations inside those `.map()` statements. And they probably should have been written as `.forEach()` for clarity. Or probably even better with a spread operator. The expected return is the value of `this.feedItem`. So it's not because the `.map()` statements lack a  `return`